# In My CA PPM css is not working i don't know what is the problem exactly?

Tags: css, clarity

I am using CA PPM web software and i am adding external css into my html page but that css are not loaded or working or you can say not applying.

there is warning in console like

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   application/download:
>   "https://cppm9267-dev.ondemand.ca.com/niku/app?action=dms.viewFile&RhXm0r7tSeUqEr=true&fileId=5042897&filedownload=filedownload&RhXm0r7tSeUqEr=true".

how can i solve this can anyone please help me in this?
 thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi you have to include a css file in the style tag or import style-sheet only it looks like you are trying to import any other mime type file.

Comment: i already include that css file in style tag with text/css mime type but still its not working

Comment: file which you are referring is the css file, what extension file you're including in the style tag?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cppm9267-dev.ondemand.ca.com/niku/app?action=dms.viewFile&RhXm0r7tSeUqEr=true&fileId=5042885&filedownload=filedownload&RhXm0r7tSeUqEr=true">

Comment: the file which you;re including is not opening in the browser as css file, its good to copy that css file in and create a css file locally as extension .css file and include it.

Comment: i also tried that bt if i am doing that there will be an error like

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'https://cppm9267-dev.ondemand.ca.com/niku/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Hello, Please read the warning it is saying that you are trying to include html file which off course not supported by the style tag include a css file only file which you including is not a css file

Comment: have you ever working with CA PPM?

Comment: What do you mean by "my HTML page"?   is it a personal HTML portlet? In any event you will find more info in the official CA PPM(Clarity) community https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-ppm/content